# Cómo agregar datos como columna nueva a una tabla ya extraida de la web?

Tags: r

Ya construí un script que extrae los datos de una tabla alojada en la web, ya puedo visualizar las tablas pero para complementarlo necesito agregar los datos del proveedor como una columna de la tabla que ya está construida, me gustaría saber cómo puedo extraer los datos del proveedor para agregarlos a mi tabla.

Script

```
library(rvest)

urls.colombia.compra.microsoft <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")


base.colombia.compra.microsft <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.microsoft, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.microsft

urls.colombia.compra.google <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                               0:11, 
                               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Google&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

base.colombia.compra.google <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.google, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.google

urls.colombia.compra.nube <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
                                      0:11, 
                                      "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=Nube%20Pública%20III&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

base.colombia.compra.nube <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.nube, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

base.colombia.compra.nube

base.consolidada.colombia.compra <- data.table::rbindlist(list(base.colombia.compra.microsft, 
                        base.colombia.compra.google, 
                        base.colombia.compra.nube), idcol = 'id')

base.consolidada.colombia.compra

all_urls <- paste0('https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/', base.consolidada.colombia.compra$`Orden de Compra`)

new_res <- purrr::map_df(all_urls, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]] %>% dplyr::mutate(order_number = basename(.x), .before = 1))

new_res


Base.articulos.colombia.compra <- new_res %>% dplyr::filter(!is.na(No))
```

Los datos de proveedor se ven así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Alejandro Chaves a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el nombre del proveedor, tienes que acceder a la página de la orden de compra, y en esta buscar el nodo apropiado, por ejemplo:

```
oc <- 72775
url.oc <-"https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/"
url.oc <- paste0(url.oc, oc) 

url.oc %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="order_header_readable_status"]') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  `[[`(2)

[1] "Unión Temporal DELL EMC"
```

Esto mismo habrá que repetirlo por cada orden de compra que hubieras obtenido en alguna de tus consultas, por ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

url.oc <-"https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/"
base.colombia.compra.microsft %>% 
  select(`Orden de Compra`) %>% 
  map_df(~paste0(url.oc, .x)) %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  map(~.x %>% read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="order_header_readable_status"]') %>% 
        html_text() %>% 
        `[[`(2)) %>% 
  unlist() -> base.colombia.compra.microsft$proveedor
```